# unexpected Proguard Error after adding Admob

Tags: android, admob, android-proguard

I added admob last day in my project and I added proguard parameters as per the document provided by Admob inside the file.Our admob is inside another Library project folder which is shared and common to our 25 other projects, We did this so that it will be easy to change inside one project and just export with required details.Google play services are again called inside this Library project.
while exporting, we are getting below error

```
[2015-11-28 10:59:45 - AppName] Dx Uncaught translation error: com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: local 0000: invalid
[2015-11-28 10:59:45 - AppName] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2015-11-28 10:59:45 - AppName] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

Below is what our pro-guard looks like

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-ignorewarnings

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { public *; }

-keep public class com.google.ads.** { public *; }


-keep class com.vungle.** { public *; }
-keep class javax.inject.*
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class dagger.*

-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}


-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
   public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.preference.PreferenceActivity {
    public void settings_activity(android.preference.PreferenceActivity );
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175971

Answer (score 0):

That is an issue with the Play Services.

It is currently reported here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=187483 and will be fixed in a future release.

That thread also has some possible fixes for the issue:

1. Recompile external libs with the version of the Play Services you use
2. Disable obfuscation